# Spring Boot Admin client cannot register

Tags: spring-boot-admin

Spring Boot Admin Version: 2.0.4

I'm trying to support LDAP security to logon to Spring Boot Admin but also support BasicAuthentication for the client registering to the SPA server.  With LDAP completely turned off, I cannot get the client to register with the server.

The error I get

> Failed to register application as Application(name=spring-boot-application, managementUrl=....

**Server application.yml**

```
spring.security.user.name: admin
spring.security.user.password: admin
```

Security that I have configured but I do have LDAP turned off, I'm just trying to secure the endpoints at this time.

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String adminContextPath;

    public SecurityConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
        this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
    }

    @Autowired
    private LDAPConfig ldapConfig;

    /**
     * Configure LDAP as AuthN manager.
     * @param auth
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        try {
            auth
                    .eraseCredentials(false)
                    .ldapAuthentication()
                    .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(new DSTLdapAuthoritiesPopulator())
                    .userDnPatterns(ldapConfig.getUserDnPatterns())
                    .contextSource()
                    .url(ldapConfig.getUrl());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Taken from official example: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.4/#_securing_spring_boot_admin_server
     * Configure login page.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.httpBasic();

        if (ldapConfig.isEnabled()) {
            // @formatter:off
            SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
            successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
            successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl(adminContextPath + "/");

            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/assets/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(adminContextPath + "/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().loginPage(adminContextPath + "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and()
                    .logout().logoutUrl(adminContextPath + "/logout").and()
                    .httpBasic().and()
                    .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .ignoringAntMatchers(
                            adminContextPath + "/instances",
                            adminContextPath + "/actuator/**"
                    );
            // If grant-access-to-groups is not configured in application.yml, any WSS-MASTER users are allowed to login to BootAdmin
            if( ldapConfig.getGrantAccessToGroups() == null ) {
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
            } else {
                // Only users in the group are allowed to login to BootAdmin.
                // secure all access to only a certain group of users
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole(ldapConfig.getGrantAccessToGroups());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Using the Petclinic Spring Boot app
2.1.0-SNAPSHOT (Having this newer version may be my issue, not sure)

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/manage
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:8081
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

# Secure the registration at the server.
spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.password=admin

# This secures the client endpoints
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin

# These are used by the server to access protected endpoints.
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.name=admin
spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.password=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also setting the server properties

spring.boot.admin.username: admin

spring.boot.admin.password: admin

In Server application.yml

Comment: I added this but didn't seem to make a difference.  I also added back the dependency spring-boot-starter-security which this prompted me to logon with admin and admin, but the client still isn't registering.

Comment: Ok. Worth a try.

Comment: I have a slightly different setup. (No LDAP at all). I also strugled at first to have the clients register. When I debugged exceptions on server it turned out to be a tomcat issue where the server didn't allow host names formatted as aaa.bbb-ccc. Downgrading spring-boot-version to 2.0.1. Made it work for me. I'll link to the tomcat-issue